# Where's the Markdown support on careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I **[love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24897/stackoverflow-careers/25221#25221)** the site, however:

- It's just *not the same* without **Markdown**
- How am I supposed to [get noticed](http://www.codexon.com/posts/simple-tips-to-get-stackoverflow-reputation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We weren't willing to open the

> > > > > ## *MARKDOWN PANDORA'S BOX!!!!1!*

in v1.

I am open to hearing opinions on this though.

Comment: At least basic markdown for headers, bullets, and bold/italics. The problem with not having markdown is that it's **impossible** to format information.

Comment: Jeff, but without bulleted lists and **bold** text, how will we make our answers.. err CVs stand out?

Comment: I would like to express the HTML hr, b, p, i, li and basic linking functionalities. I want to be able to produce professional-looking product, essentially. :-)

Comment: This was almost 7 years ago! We still don't have markdown? :(

Answer (score 7):

No kidding. Nothing like pasting links into "Projects and Links" only to find them displayed raw, with the ends (most relevant part!) cut off.

Don't need full-on embedded HTML support, don't even need the more complex parts of markdown... code, headers, lists and linking would go a long way.

Comment: can you email us directly with ideas?

Answer (score 4):

@Jeff, In response to [your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24920/wheres-the-markdown-support-on-careers-stackoverflow-com/24922#24922),

I don't see why you *wouldn't* allow markdown to let us at least **approximate traditional CV formatting** (headers, bold/italics, bullets, etc). But if "pandora's box" means abusive use of formatting(?)... if a user wants to make themselves look bad, that's their choice.

I haven't used the site, yet so I'm not sure I can speak *intelligently* about it. But what am I missing?

Comment: Also needs Cornify feature...

Answer (score 2):

I would like it to *just work*. The same parsing code that's used on Stack Overflow should be used on Careers. I don't want to think about what works over here and what works over there.

I understand your hesitance to open Pandora's box with version 1. It might not be a bad idea to start out with the same restrictions you have on new users. I would be fine with that (for a while).